# How can I force a subtitle track to be set as active on an MP4 video?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, subtitles, matroska

I'm converting .mkv's to mp4 and it's working, however the issue is that when I open the .mp4, the subtitle track is disabled by default.

I have to manually select it as such:

[image]

How can I make it so that it's forced on the video, so that for instance I could upload it somewhere, the subtitles would appear above it?

If that's of any relevance, I'm using this ffmpeg command to convert from MKV to MP4:

```
ffmpeg -i myMovie.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:1 -c:s mov_text test.mp4
```

Comment: Flag it as en-forced. idk exactly how, but it works when there's a bit of 'foreign' in a movie.